# Creating a snapshot of a linux system

Tags: linux, snapshot

I want to do the following - Save the current state of my linux OS(centOS6.5). Do some changes (more specifically inject a fault and test some service to check how it behaves when that particular type of a fault occurs.) Then restore the system back to the saved state. I am not able to figure out how to do this on a linux system. I have a machine with centOS 6.5 with an ext4 filesystem.Also this is a physical server and not a virtual machine.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Physical server, or virtual machine ?

Comment: I recommend to run your OS on virtualization software like VirtualBox.  It nicely supports snapshots.

Comment: It is a physical server. I need to do this on multiple machines(physical servers) and cannot change the configuration to run my OS on a virtualization software.

Comment: It usually needs an additional meta layer like virtualization to support system snapshots.  It would be very hard to make physical servers behave themselves as if they were under control of it from firmware and bootloader level.

Answer (score 9):

You can use rsync to backup the entire system.

```
rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /* /path/to/backup/folder
```

There's a awesome article at [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync) about it

Comment: That's quite short to be the best option for me. Of course if you don't have `rsync` you can use `dd` wich i use to backup my usb drives.

Answer (score 8):

I would keep it simple and clone it.  Boot a live system from USB (easiest is Ubuntu from a USB thumb drive, I find), then dump your hard disk to a different partition (or external hard drive etc.), e.g.

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=64M of=/mnt/my_mounted_backup_drive/backup-sda1
```

where you need to replace `/dev/sda1` with your root (`/`) partition.  Do the same with other partitions (like the one for `/boot`, `/boot/efi`, `/home`) where applicable.

If you need to save space, you could do

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=64M | gzip --fast | dd bs=32M of=/mnt/my_mounted_backup_drive/backup-sda1.gz
```

or, more complicated, much slower but saving a few more bytes,

```
mkdir -p /mnt/linux
mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/linux
cd /mnt/linux
tar cvJf /mnt/my_mounted_backup_drive/linux-backup.tar.xz .??* *
```

You can then restore the other way around, e.g.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/linux
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/linux
cd /mnt/linux
tar xvJf /mnt/my_mounted_backup_drive/linux-backup.tar.xz
```

or

```
dd /mnt/my_mounted_backup_drive/backup-sda1.gz bs=32M | gzip --decompress | dd bs=64M of=/dev/sda1
```

(careful where you are writing your data, this deletes everything on `/dev/sda1`, so get it right the first time :-)

Comment: PS: If you expect something to go really wrong backup the partition table, like `dd if=/dev/sda bs=64M count=2 of=/mnt/my_mounted_backup_drive/backup-sda`.  When restoring you need to be careful not to write too many blocks back to disk here - cannot say how many without looking at your partition layout.  Restore up to (not including) the block where your first partition starts according to `gdisk` or `fdisk`.

Answer (score 3):

How about using rsync or rsnapshot to essentially backup the local machine? Once you test is done, simply restore the backup.

http://rsnapshot.org/

http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Similarly, you can use LVM:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org), which will save the contents of the file system to a compressed file and restore the filesystem when extracting the data.

Here is an example from the [documentation](http://www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart):

```
fsarchiver savefs /mnt/backup/gentoo-rootfs.fsa /dev/sda1
```

You can also use multi-threaded compression, and restoring is straightforward:

```
fsarchiver restfs /mnt/backup/gentoo-rootfs.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sda1
```