# Is it possible to save hibernation state in linux?

Tags: linux, command, hibernate

I'm wondering if there is a command in Linux which lets you "hibernate" but without "shutting down" your computer. That way I could continue working but if I reboot it would return to its previous state.

As I understand, hibernation works by saving the RAM to swap disk so theoretically all the command has to do is copy the RAM to swap. I'm looking for something like this:

```
# swapon /dev/sda1
# hibernate-but-not-shutdown
# swapoff /dev/sda1
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: What basically you want to do is to take a *snapshot* of the current system. See the answers here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226144/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-linux-system